# Для чего повторно генерировать исключения?

Tags: php, laravel, исключения

При изучении исключений в laravel увидел пример наподобии этого:

```
try {
        return $this->model->create($data);
    } catch (QueryException $e) {
        throw new ProductCreateErrorException($e);
    }
```

Предположительно, `QueryException` - общий класс исключений для БД, а `ProductUpdateErrorException` - класс исключений для добавления товара в БД. Объясните подробно, что здесь происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не про php, в общем-то, а про подход а целом. Типичная делегация на уровень выше.

В `catch` блоке не всегда можно обработать все исключения, к примеру, в силу того, что этот метод ничего не знает про предметную область. Ну да, там исключение при работе с базой. Что делать? Раз не получается обработать исключение, то разумно кидать исключение выше по стеку вызовов.

Почему наверх передаётся именно `ProductCreateErrorException`, а не оригинальное исключение? Тоже разные мотивы. Если, к примеру, это какая-то библиотека, а метод должен "что-то добавить", то дженерик исключение `QueryException` вызывающему мало о чём скажет, а так `ProductCreateErrorException` говорит вызывающему методу, что это "что-то" не удалось создать.

Answer (score 1):

что бы разные исключения приводить к единому стандарту, например:

при создании продукта в разных местах могут броситься разные исключения,
но для логики приложения не важно в каком месте произошла какая ошибка,
для него важно что создание продукта не возможна.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае причина может быть только одна - где-то ниже по коду есть catch, который ловит ProductCreateErrorException. Но лично я бы не злоупотреблял такими кунштюками.

Обычно же исключение перевыбрасвается после обработки ошибки. Например, в случае ошибки транзакции мы сначала должны откатить её, а потом снова бросить исключение, чтобы ошибка обработалась стандартным порядком.